# Watson Conversation supports nested Intents?

Tags: watson-conversation

Does anyone have a good example of nested Intents especially where #yes and #no are child nodes. The situation i am getting is that the API is returning with Intent value but the output text from "Anything else"!

Comment: Have you got a solution to this problem ?

Comment: [Import this JSON and see if it helps](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Tk_bFJHtEIQzJ4Y1BQWEdSdEU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented feature that if the confidence is <0.2 then it will automatically jump to the `Anything Else` node.

So to get it to go to the right intent node, you will need to train the intents a bit better.

Alternatively for dealing with multiple intents you can access the intents array using the `intents` object.

Example:

```
intents[0].matches('yes|no')
OR
intents[1].matches('yes|no')
```

From a coding point of view you can set the flag `alternate_intents` and then review the returned intents array.

Comment: but how about when I am getting a confidence equal to 1 and always the node_visited is just anything else ?

Comment: In that case you don't have your nodes matching that intent. Common mistake is forgetting the # at the start of the node name.